# Winforms: Create object in designer and customize it

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, windows-forms-designer

Iam creating a new Component in Winforms (C#). This Component get some Properties to modify the behaviour. The user should pull the Component on his form, set some Properties and ready. If i want to set a Property of common ComponentType (like Form) there is no Problem. But i got a `BindingList<>()` Property which isn't generated by the Designer.

[image]

The StandardItems Property can't be set. The user can add items via the AddItem-Dialog but the BindingList is never created.

```
[Category("Einstellungen")]
[Browsable(true)]      
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public BindingList<StandardItems> StandardItems
{
   get { return _standardItems; }
   set
   {
     _standardItems = value;
     _standardItems.ListChanged -= _standardItems_ListChanged;
     _standardItems.ListChanged += _standardItems_ListChanged;
    }
}
```

I thought the Designer would create the list for me. So that iam directly able to add items via designer.

This is Designer-Code for my Component:

```
this.menuBar1.BarManager = null;
this.menuBar1.DockCol = 0;
this.menuBar1.OptionsBar.AllowQuickCustomization = false;
this.menuBar1.OptionsBar.DrawDragBorder = false;
this.menuBar1.OptionsBar.RotateWhenVertical = false;
this.menuBar1.OptionsBar.UseWholeRow = true;
this.menuBar1.ParentForm = null;
this.menuBar1.PopupMenu = null;
```

I thought there must be something like:

```
this.menuBar1.StandardItems = null;
```

or

```
this.menuBar1.StandardItems = new BindingList<StandardItems>();
```

So that i can add Items via the Designer and the designer adds code like this:

```
this.menuBar1.StandardItems.Add(new StandardItem());
```

Is there any attribute or something iam missing?

Comment: BindingList is a generic type. It needs to know what type of an object it should create. How do you see a common editor for BindingList<T>? Or, do you need a specific editor only for BindingList<StandardItems>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your items in your custom component, because the Designer does not know how to create new `BindingList<StandardItems>`. So, if you create your `BindingList` by yourself, then Designer can use this list to add the values to it:

```
public class MenuBar : Component
{
    BindingList<StandardItems> _standardItems = new BindingList<StandardItems>()

    [Category("Einstellungen")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]    
    public BindingList<StandardItems> StandardItems
    {
        get { return _standardItems; }
        set
        {
            _standardItems = value;
            _standardItems.ListChanged -= _standardItems_ListChanged;
            _standardItems.ListChanged += _standardItems_ListChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is your designer code that can be generated:

```
StandardItems standardItems1 = new StandardItems();
StandardItems standardItems2 = new StandardItems();

//

this.menuBar1.BarManager = null;
this.menuBar1.DockCol = 0;
this.menuBar1.OptionsBar.AllowQuickCustomization = false;
this.menuBar1.OptionsBar.DrawDragBorder = false;
this.menuBar1.OptionsBar.RotateWhenVertical = false;
this.menuBar1.OptionsBar.UseWholeRow = true;
this.menuBar1.ParentForm = null;
this.menuBar1.PopupMenu = null;
standardItems1.SomeProperty = 0;
standardItems1.SomeAnotherProperty = "Property0";
standardItems2.SomeProperty = 1;
standardItems2.SomeAnotherProperty = "Property1";
this.menuBar1.StandardItems.Add(standardItems1);
this.menuBar1.StandardItems.Add(standardItems2);
```